# why can i still call init() without arguments in Swift

Tags: swift

why can i call ABTextField.init() without providing arguments, it still calls configure inside ? (although I haven't provided the convenience init yet)

```
class ABTextField: UITextField {
   
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    private func configure() {}

ABTextField.init() // no error
```

```
 - super: UITextField
    - super: UIControl
      - super: UIView
        - super: UIResponder
          - super: NSObject
```

this is the order of types called up to NSObject, is it calling init sequentially on types up to NSObject ?
If I create an init function on ABTextField, does it convert the overridden init function to a designated init? so does init function inherit NSObject to convience init ? (priority in order designated > override > init of NSObject)

Comment: you're wrong it calls configure that's why i asked why in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield) inherits from [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol), which inherits from [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview), which inherits from [`UIResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder), which inherits from [`NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject), which contains [this initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418641-init):

```
init()
```

> The root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies, from which subclasses inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects.

Since you haven't defined a custom `init` for your `ABTextField` yet, you automatically inherit `NSObject`'s `init`, according to the [Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID222):

> **Rule 1**
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.

Comment: why when i create init() function inside ABTextField it can't call NSObject's init() function anymore, is it when I create init function it automatically converts to convenience init calling the overridden init() function?

Comment: @LeoDabus check my newly edited question , thank

Comment: @csemorf I recommend testing yourself by making your own classes: `class A { init() {} }` `class B: A {}` `let b = B()` and so on.

Comment: Btw if my answer worked/made sense, can you click the green checkmark to accept it?

Comment: okeeeeee ( btw, it requires many characters)